# I am attempting to create a filter that will find matches in two arrays

Tags: angularjs

I have two arrays of strings, title and title2 and I want to create a third array of the matches. I did not have luck with the for loop inside of the filter and I thought about using forEach, however, that seems to require a dictionary type object.

```
        .filter('findMatches', function() {   
        //   this filter finds matching strings
        return function isMatch(title, title2){
        var matches = [];
        //for (i = 0; i < title.length; i++) { 
        matches.push("");

        return matches;
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful but I previously wrote this in python as shown below, However, I want to do this now as an angularJS filter if that dynamically finds matchies if that is possible.

```
    Both = []
    for x in C:
        if x in D:
            Both.append(x)
    for x in range(len(Both)):
        Both[x]=str(Both[x])
    Final = []
    for x in set(Both):
        Final.append(x)
    MissingA = []
    for x in C:
        if x not in Final and x not in MissingA:
            MissingA.append(x)
    for x in range(len(MissingA)):
        MissingA[x]=str(MissingA[x])
    MissingB = []
    for x in D:
        if x not in Final and x not in MissingB:
            MissingB.append(x)
    for x in range(len(MissingB)):
        MissingB[x]=str(MissingB[x])
```

Thanks for the help to the two people below. I still cannot figure this out. I tried method two below here but it is not working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SEi3DU0PoOSPx9AZBrzP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that a custom filter is a good fit for this problem.  I would probably either create a service that would return it as a single array that I could perform matching on (or just have the service perform the matching).

A simpler solution would be something like the following though:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="query" />

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="title in title1 | filter: query">{{title}}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="title in title2 | filter: query">{{title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it as

```
    .filter('findMatches', function() {   
         return function isMatch(title, title2){
            var matches = [];
            for (i = 0; i < title.length; i++) { 
              if(title2.indexOf(title[i]) > -1){
                matches.push(title[i]);
              }
            }
             return matches;
         }
})
```